# Angular-Firebase Google Authentication (Error 403: restricted_client)

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, google-authentication, google-signin

I'm going through an Angular/Firebase tutorial and I'm trying to implement Google Login to Angular/Firebase application. I'm doing everything exactly as it is in the tutorial but I get an error. What I did:

1) In firebase Authentication panel I enabled E-mail and Google Sing-in methods.

2) In my Login component, I implemented the following code: (which works on Mosh's tutorial)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from "firebase";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  login() {
   this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
}
```

However, I get this error:

Error 403: restricted_client
This app is not yet configured to make OAuth requests. To do that, set up the app’s OAuth consent screen in the Google Cloud Console.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YonZfCWW06M

What should I do, do you have any suggestions about what might be wrong and what can I do to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create  OAuth consent key in your Google Dashboard

[image]

click credentials

[image]

create OAuth consent and add key to project
[image]

Comment: Thank you! This helped me figure out the answer. For anyone reading this - You need to add LOGO in this section and just click save. That will fix this error.

Comment: if it hels ans resolve mark as correct it will be help for futur users to